# What characters are active by default in TeX?

Tags: active-characters

Since the character `~` has a catcode of 13, it is considered active. I can (ab)use this by executing something like the code
`` \let~\catcode ~`a8 `` which assigns the character `a` a catcode of 8 (for subscript), without having to do `` \catcode`~13 `` first.

What other characters are considered active by default in TeX? In other words, what characters have a catcode of 13 by default?

Comment: `~` is the only one usable in latex. In pdftex all characters above 127 are active but if you mess with them you will break the encoding support.

Comment: Just noting that your question title says "always active", while your question says "active by default".  These are not the same thing, since the catcode of `~` can be changed on a whim.

Comment: Good catch, changed.

Comment: Looks like a rather impractical question, but you can just do a loop to print out catcode of every characters. Last time I check, the discretionary hyphen ("A0) is in non-pdflatex engine.

Answer (score 3):

plain always has character 12 (form feed) and 126 (tilde) as active which is not surprising.

In LaTeX the situation depends on the engine used. With pdflatex characters 128-225 are active for encoding support; in xelatex and lualatex character 173 (U+00AD "soft hyphen") is declared active and given the meaning `\-` (discretionary hyphen).

In table form:

| format / engine | tex | pdftex | xetex | luatex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **plain** | 12 126 | 12 126 | 12 126 | 12 126 |
| **LaTeX** | / | 1-8 11 12 14-31 126 128-255 | 12 126 173 | 12 126 173 |
| **conTeXt** | / | / | / | 124 126 |
| **AmS-TeX** | / | 12 64 126 | / | / |
| **OpTeX** | / | / | / | 126 160 |

Overall only `~` seems to be universal.

The following test file is used:

```
\ifx\documentclass\undefined \else
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
\fi
\csname starttext\endcsname

\newcount\curr
\newcount\upper

\ifx\numexpr\undefined
    \upper="100
    \def\n{^^J}
\else
    \ifx\pdftexbanner\undefined
        \upper="10000
        \edef\n{\Uchar"000A}
    \else
        \upper="100
        \def\n{^^J}
    \fi
\fi

\newlinechar=10
\message{\n\n}
    
\count0=0
\loop
    \ifnum\catcode\curr=\active
        \message{ \the\curr}
    \fi
    \advance\curr 1
\ifnum\curr<\upper \repeat

\message{\n\n}

\csname stoptext\endcsname \end{document}
```